# Reducing adjective clauses to phrases and putting commas

Tags: adjective-phrases

What is the best choice?

1. English enthusiasts, the people dedicating most of their spair time to learning the English language, are very interesting and successful people.
2. English enthusiasts the people, dedicating most of their spair time to learning the English language, are very interesting and successful people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one.

"the people dedicating most of their SPARE time to learning the English language" is a subordinate clause.  It's additional information and the sentence still makes sense without that information.  If "the people" is there, the sentence doesn't make sense.  Let's remove the subordinate clause and see what happens:

a. English enthusiasts are very interesting and successful people.

b. English enthusiasts the people are very interesting and successful people.

b doesn't make sense, whereas a does.  So your first sentence is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The first is correct.  The comma belongs in front of "the people" because the entire phrase within the commas in the first example is a clause that clarifies who English enthusiasts are.

Your second example doesn't make sense and couldn't be interpreted to have another meaning.

Also, the correct spelling for "spair" is spare.

Have a nice day.